# Given a $T$- invariant subspace find a $T$-invariant director complement

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ a finite dimensional vector space, $T$ an operator of $V$ and $W$ a $T$-invariant subspace then find a subspace $Y$ such that $V$ is the direct sum of $W$ and $Y$.

Since $W$ is $T$-invariant there is an eigen vector on $W$.
My idea of proof is to choose the subspaces asociated to diferent eigen values but i can't do a formal proof

Answer (score 0):

In general, $T$-invariant complements don't exist. Operators $T$ for which every invariant subspace has an invariant complement are called semisimple. It's equivalent to the minimal polynomial of $T$ being squarefree.

Comment: user323524 (Somehow it won't take my "@") What is the difference between the minimal polynomial being squarefree and diagonalizability?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp There are two ways that they can be different: (i) if the base field $K$ is not algebraically closed; for example, 2x2 rotation matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ are semisimple but generally not diagonalizable, and (ii) if $\overline{K}$ is not separable over $K$, where minimal polynomials can be squarefree (even irreducible) in $K$ but not have distinct roots in $\overline{K}$

Comment: user323524 Thank you. I asked because I am used to work in $\mathbb C$. In this case they are the same thing, right?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Yes, if we were over $\mathbb{C}$ then this would be equivalent to diagonalizable

Comment: user323524 Thank you.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Thanks a lot. Is it related with representation of finite groups? Because of the semisimple álgebra.